# Custom contacts selection in iPhone like in SMS/Email apps

Tags: iphone, user-interface, selection, contacts

I am creating an app that allows users to select a list of friends from their contacts list. I can open up the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController, but how can I make the chosen contacts to display like in the image below (the Rosa Golijan part):

[image]
<sub>(source: [gawkerassets.com](http://cache.gawkerassets.com/assets/images/4/2010/06/340x_emailimage.jpg))</sub>

Basically, a list of light-blue rounded rect buttons, and you can easily delete one if needed.
I guess I can do it from scratch with a bunch of UIButtons or something, but it's a lot of work and can be quite error-prone. Just wondering if any of you knows of some existing sample code or something? Or any advice to push me in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you found any solution for this? Please share and help.

Answer (score 3):

TITokenFieldView is a control which mimics the "To: field"

[Take a Look at TITokenFieldView](https://github.com/thermogl/TITokenFieldView)